# binding selectionArgs to a FTS3 query that spans across multiple columns

Tags: android, full-text-search, android-sqlite, fts3

I construct selection string to perform FTS3 search across multiple columns:

```
final String selection = "table MATCH 'column1:? OR column2:?'"
```

I am also passing selectionArgs containing the search terms.  The problem is that I'm getting an exception during argument binding:

> 11-30 13:22:27.475  26281-26323/com.example.myapp
>   W/SuggestionsAdapter﹕ Search suggestions query threw an exception.
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)

When I replace question marks in the MATCH argument string with hard-coded search terms and set `selectionArgs = null`, the query works and returns correct results.

How can I bind selectionArgs to a FTS3 query that searches across multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach worked for me:

- Use `String.format()` to construct `selectionArgs`, using search terms as arguments.
- Use single argument to construct `selection`

In code:

```
final String selection = "table MATCH ?"
final String[] selectionArgs = { String.format("column1:%s* OR column2:%s*", term1, term2) };
```